# Условный Оператор python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
while(True):
    if new_node.value == temp.value:
        return False
    if temp.left is None:
        temp.left = new_node
        return True
    temp = temp.left
else:
    if temp.right is None:
        temp.right = new_node
        return True
    temp = temp.right
```

Может кто объяснить эту часть: `temp = temp.left` и `temp = temp.right` в каком случае эта строчка сработает?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, код какой-то странный...
В нём `else` не имеет никакого смысла по двум причинам.

1. В теле цикла нет ни одного `break`. Соответственно, цикл может завершиться только естественным путём (т.е. по условию цикла), значит можно записать так:

```
while(True):
    if new_node.value == temp.value:
        return False
    if temp.left is None:
        temp.left = new_node
        return True
    temp = temp.left
 
if temp.right is None:
     temp.right = new_node
     return True
temp = temp.right
```

Но,

2. Цикл бесконечный, и выход из него только по `return` (с выходом из функции), значит код после `else` вообще никогда не выполнится. Итого имеем:

```
while(True):
    if new_node.value == temp.value:
        return False
    if temp.left is None:
        temp.left = new_node
        return True
    temp = temp.left
```

Судя по названиям переменных и структурам данных, это кусок функции, которая должна была добавлять новое значение в дерево. Цикл пытается идти по левым ветвям дерева и, если у очередного узла уже значение равное новому, то функция возвращает `False` (добавление не удалось). А если цикл дошёл до конца (очередная ссылка на левую ветвь равна `None`), то добавляет туда новый узел и возвращает `True`.
Проблема в том, что нет сравнения больше/меньше и по правой ветке дерева данный код никогда не идёт.

По идее, там должно быть что-то такое:

```
# temp = root_node
while(True):
    if new_node.value == temp.value: # такое значение в дереве уже есть ?
        return False
    if new_node.value < temp.value:  # новое значение меньше ? идём налево
        if temp.left is None:        # конец ветки ?
            temp.left = new_node     # добавляем новый узел слева
            return True
        temp = temp.left             # иначе переходим к следующему узлу по левой ветке
    else:                            # иначе идём направо
        if temp.right is None:       # конец ветки ?
            temp.right = new_node    # добавляем новый узел справа
            return True
        temp = temp.right            # иначе переходим к следующему узлу по правой ветке
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я просто не понял, почему синтаксически отступ там, то есть `temp = temp.left` почему не после `return True сразу идет`, это означает что он как `else` срабатывает, просто его не написали или как понять?

Comment: Фактически да, он как `else` срабатывает. Но т.к. под `if` стоит `return`, то `else` можно и не писать, ибо код дальше пойдёт только если `if` не сработает. И на одном уровне с `return` после самого `return` вообще ничего писать смысла нет - `return` же выполнится и функция на этом работу закончит.

Answer (score 0):

1. Блок `else` сработает после циклов в том случае, если только выполнение цикла не было прервано оператором break, return или raise.
2. `temp.left is None` - проверяет у объекта `temp` атрибут `left` на `None`, если он таким является, тогда срабатывает положительная ветка.

Не понял почему минусы у ответа - я всего лишь дал ответ на вопрос... Для тех кто поставил - вот вам пример:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    if i > 20:
        print('Я сработал!')
        break
else:
    print('Увы - ничего не произошло =(')
```

Итог этой программы будет:

```
Увы - ничего не произошло =(
```

Но если поставить условие `while i < 100:`, то тогда итог работы будет:

```
Я сработал!
```

Comment: @splash58, исправил